# soapui - assign XML string to variable - groovy script

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

I'm having to convert some JMeter performance tests to soapui (using groovy script) and I have a quick question about preserving carriage returns in XML strings if that's ok.

Little embaressed to be asking this, but I'm not a coder - hence my confusion.

In my JMeter script it states

```
String FinalXML=
"<someXMLheader>\n"+
    "<someXMLcontent>\n"+
    "</someXMLcontent>\n"+
"</someXMLheader>";

vars.put("FinalXML1", FinalXML)
```

I've done some reading about doing the equivalent which I believe is assigning a string to a variable (like I say - I'm not a coder!), so I suspect my groovy script would appear something like as follows:

```
def FinalXML1 = "<someXMLheader>
                     <someXMLcontent>
                     </someXMLcontent>
                </someXMLheader>"
```

As you can see, I've stripped out the quotation marks for each line along with the carriage returns '\n"+' (compared with the JMeter beanshell script) but I'm wondering if this is correct and ALSO,

1. Does the XML string need to be on one line?
2. How can I preserve the carriage returns (whitespace) between the XML elements?

As stated above, I'm not a coder which is why I'm asking a simple question like this.

Many thanks to anyone who responds...

Answer (score 0):

First to your Groovy question: To create a string that has special characters, such as newlines, in Groovy you need to enclose it in tripple-quotes, like so:

```
def FinalXML1 = """<someXMLheader>
                     <someXMLcontent>
                     </someXMLcontent>
                </someXMLheader>"""
```

A very basic Google search would have turned [that](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#all-strings) up!

Second to your your XML question: that depends! Most XML parsers will strip off whitespace, some will not. For literal strings it is different again. Note that in the above example, the node `<someXMLcontent>` not only has a newline, but the newline is also followed by 21 space characters. Try it out on your system, and see what happens.

Also note that none of this is SoapUI specific.

Comment: I did do a google search but I wasn't sure what I was looking for - google only works if you use the appropriate search term in your query and I obviously wasn't!  Thanks